# How to import a video that is being saved as a videowriter from html

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, flask

Now, using two threads, one is using the thread to save the video on the webcam as a file, and the other is passing the file on to the html and showing it on the web as html. I don't know much about the web, but I'd like to pass the video variable that is being saved as a radar_template by flask and receive it from html to url_for and print it out. But the video is not being printed.

Python code for storing videos.

```
fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
out = VideoWriter('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MRCNN_pure/static/image/output.mp4', fourcc, 13.0, (1280, 720))

_lock = threading.Lock()

def webcam(capture):
  while True:
    frame_pos = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    frame_count = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

    grabbed, frame = capture.read()
    if not grabbed:
      print ("Not grabbed.")
      break;

    if grabbed:
      _lock.acquire()
      out.write(frame)
      _lock.release()
```

The following is a flask execution code that passes it to the render_template.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route("/")
def home()-> 'html':
  return render_template('test.html', output = "image/output.mp4")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Next is the html file.

```
<body>
    <h1>HTML5 오픈 커뮤니티</h1>
    <p>이 자료는 <a href="http://www.htmlfive.co.kr">HTML5 오픈 커뮤니티</a>에서 배포합니다.</p>

    {% if True %}
      <video controls autoplay preload="metadata" width="50%" src="{{ url_for('static',filename=output) }}" type='video/mp4'>
        not working
      </video>
      <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=output)}}">
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

I can turn over another complete video file and print it on the web, but I can't print the video I'm saving. Is there a good way?

Comment: do you have problem to open your video in any video player ? Maybe video file is wrong.

Comment: is your webcam gets frames in size `(1280, 720)` ? If it gets frames in different size then `VideoWriter(..., (1280, 720))` will not save it and you have to do `frame = cv.resize((1280, 720), frame)` to save it.

Comment: The result of the reshape on the frame was 1280, 720, so I saved it with this.

Comment: do you have problem to open your video in any video player ? Did you try to run it in `debug=True` - I'm not sure if Flask serve static files when you don't use `debug` more. In normal mode it may need other server for static files.

Comment: When I downloaded the written video file and play it, it works in local video player.
I programmed it in Google Colaboratory so, I can not use  {debug=True} on flask...
What other server means?

Comment: normally you should  runs  `app.run()` only when you develop Flask code and  then it uses built-in web server to send generated and static files. But after developing you should use other web server to run it - ie. Apache, Nginx, uWSGI, Gunicorn - and then Flask serves only generated filles but static files are served by Apache, Nginx, uWSGI, Gunicorn because it does it faster and it uses less memory/CPU.

Comment: Oh, so you mean
making web server - flask / 
send static video file - other server rib
right? I'll try it.

Comment: if you can download video and run in local video player then it seems file is OK. You could check in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome (tab: `Network` or `Console`) if it has problem to get file when you try to display it on your page. You could also try to open your video file directly in browser to see if browser support this format (`H264` with `.mp4`)

Comment: BTW: on page ["Can I Use"](https://caniuse.com) you can see which browsers support [H264](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4) and [WEBM](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webm)

Comment: I think 2 thread reach the same file at the sametime. One thread is writing video file, and the other is opening it being written now. Actually, I want to stream the video file to web browser. Chrome support mp4, webm, ogg. I tried mp4 and webm but it doesn't work. 
So hopeless it doesn't work...

Comment: BTW: there is tutorial how to stream video from webcam as Motion-JPEG  in Flask (in real time) - [Video Streaming with Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask) and [Flask Video Streaming Revisited](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited). Tutorial uses module `camera` for Raspberry Pi but it should works also with `cv2`. And it send it without writing to file but you can send frame to browser and write in file at the same time.

Comment: I used it, but flask routing doesn't work in google colaboratory. I can't use {debug=True}, so I don't know why... Sorry I'm beginner. when using routed url in html, It has internal server error.

Comment: did you try to run it on your local computer ? As I know `google colaboratory` shouldn't have access to local webcam.

Comment: I did not try it in my local. in google colaboratory, I use pafy library to get youtube video

Comment: I tried it in my local computer now, local server did not open!

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error messages ?

Comment: BTW: you may try `app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)` on Google Colab - maybe it will resolve problem because in debug mode it tries to reload code in separated thread and it can makes problem in some programs.

Comment: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
and error message is not shiown.

Comment: it is normal information - don't bother this.

Comment: I changed the address, it works
so, now the left how can I do it in google colaboratory